# Change Wix Desktop Icon

Tags: wix

I used Wix Toolset to create setup for my WPF application, But I cant change the desktop icon

I insert:

```
<Icon Id="Icon.exe" SourceFile="icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
```

And include the file icon.ico in my Wix proect :

[image]

I think the problem in the path of SourceFile!

Please, Can you check it and tell me what I miss.

Thanks in advance

Abdulsalam

Comment: Is my solution was helpful for you, if yes please mark as answered.

Comment: the Value of the ARPPRODUCTICON property should be the ID of an <Icon> element **not** the location of the icon file.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your help, I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a reference of a root dir.

Something like that:

```
 <Icon Id="Icon.exe" SourceFile="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\icon.ico"/>
```

$(sys.CURRENTDIR) - is the location of the file you are editing this element.
From from the screenshot it's probably is product.wxs

Relative to this location find the icon.ico location.
For example:
If the icon.ico is located in inner folder called "resources" than the sourcefile attribute should be-

```
<Icon Id="Icon.exe" SourceFile="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\resources\icon.ico"/>
```

The path is how it's located on the disk and not in your VS source code tree.

The ARPPRODUCTICON property's Value should be the ID of an `<Icon>` element and not the path to the icon file.

```
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="Icon.exe" />
```

To add an icon to the desktop add Icon attribute to shortcut element like this:

```
            <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"
                Name="ORDER MS"
                Description="ORDER Managment Systrm - Resturant POS"
                Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]WixTest.exe"
                WorkingDirectory="MYAPPDIRPROPERTY"
                Icon= "Icon.exe"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Arkady for your replay, But nothing happen ! The icon for the application on the desktop and the icon in the add/remove also still not change. any idea ?

Comment: Thanks Brian Sutherland for pointing the ID of an element problem.

Comment: Thanks Arkady, I will try the latest update for your solution.

Comment: I tried the lates update for for solution, It change the application icon in add/remove programs, but the desktop icon does not change !
here (http://alrakiza.com/wix/WixTest.zip) is my small test WPF application

Comment: Thanks Arkady so such, Last thing I want to generate exe rather than msi .. I try by adding Bootstrapper project but I fail to apecifying SourceFile

<Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="*" UpgradeCode="41886d34-8c5c-4692-bb6d-8802013ce1c5">
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

  <Chain>
   <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="WixSetup.msi" /> 
  </Chain>
 </Bundle>

Comment: Please open a new question for others to get the right answer.

Comment: I will, Thanks Arkady

Comment: I Opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747762/generating-an-exe-from-msi-in-wix